# Java text on buttons is not displayed

Tags: java, swing, text, label, jbutton

I'm making simple Java swing application and text on some buttons is not displayed.

One of JButtons is with text "Clear" and it's text is displayed, but I tried setting text of other buttons to "Change Color", "Write", "c", "w", but none of them are showing this text, not even "...".

This part of (not actual) code is in the constructor of class which is extending `JFrame`:

```java
/* JPanel */ panel = new JPanel();
/* JButton */ testButton1 = new JButton("Change Color");
/* JButton */ testButton2 = new JButton("c");
panel.add(testButton);

/* this. */ pack();
```

Again, this is strange that text is only displayed only on one button, which is created the same way as others.

Comment: *which is created the same way as others.* - Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is create a JFrame with two JButtons each with different text to demonstrate your problem. And why does your code show the create of a JPanel, but you never add any components to the panel. Without a proper "MRE" we really can't tell what you are doing

Comment: My guess is you keep adding buttons to the frame, which won't work because by default a JFrame uses the BoderLayout and by default the component is added to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`. However, only a single component can be added to the CENTER. You need to first add your buttons to a panel and then add the panel to the frame. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for Swing basics.

Comment: When I moved buttons to other custom JPanel classes, text showed up.

Answer (score 0):

I build an example here.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;   
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DisplayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        run(new Display(), 400, 300);
    }

    public static void run(JFrame jFrame,int width,int height) {
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(Display.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(width, height);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }
}

class Display extends JFrame{

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton testButton = new JButton("Change Color");
    JButton clearButton = new JButton("clear");

    public Display() {
        add(testButton);
        add(clearButton);
        pack();
    }       
}
```

Notices, BorderLayout will make the later component replace the previous one,the flowLayout will show all components you added.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actual buttons (their border, you can click them)  are displayed, but their text is not.

Comment: It works well on my computer and it should works well on other computer.Maybe you can change some configurations like jdk version and test it again.My jdk is 1.7 version and the computer system is windows.